# Retrieve data from MySql db through express and Angular

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to retrieve some data from my MySql database to my Angular controller through node/express but I'm having some trouble with the routing.

In the angular controller I have a load function that does a get request:

```
    $scope.load = function ()  {
        $http.get('/users').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('success');
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
                console.log($scope.todos);

            }).
            catch(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('catch');
            console.log(status);
                console.log(data);
            });
    };
```

In my app.js I have:

```
var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', users);
```

And in my routes/users.js file I have:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var pool = require('../connection');

    /* GET users listing. */
    router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {

        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `first_name` = "Kees"', function(err, results){
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                }else{
                    console.log(results);
                }
            });

            connection.release();
        });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

When I fire the load() function in my view the app.js log returns:

> GET /users 404 54.369 ms - 1846

And the browser shows:

> GET http://localhost:3000/users 404 (Not Found)
>
> catch
>
> Object {data: "", status: 404, config: Object, statusText: "Not Found"}

What's the correct way to retrieve the data through Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app.js you have already set up the route for any calls to `/users`. That means that all the http requests in your users.js-file already has that in the url.
So this:

```
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next)
```

actually is called from example.com/users/users.

Just write it like this instead:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next)
```